# How do I make it randomly display one item from the array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am trying to make it so that when one of the words from `$hello` is typed in it randomly chooses one of the words `$bye` and displays it. At the moment when I try it, it only says 0, 1 or 2. How do I go about fixing this so it would randomly give me one of the words from the `$bye` array instead.

```
<?php
$words = $_POST['words'];
$hello = array('hello', 'hi', 'yo', 'sup');
$bye = array('bye', 'seeya', 'aurevoir');
$words = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $hello).')\b/i', '<span class="highlight">'.array_rand($bye).'</span>', $words);
echo $words;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is currently not possible to contribute to this question. Please _edit_ your question above and make the details more clear. Especially post your current code in a readable way using the builtin editors feature to format code. The current code snippet is _not_ sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = array_rand($bye);
echo $bye[$index];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hello = array("Hi", "Hola", "Yo dawg! I heard you liked words in your hello!");
$bye = array("Later","Hasta Luego","Guten Tag");
echo $bye[array_rand($hello)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use array with `preg_replace`

```
$words="this is any text bye";
$bye = array('/bye/', '/seeya/', '/aurevoir/'); //pattern

$hello=array('hello', 'hi', 'yo');  //$replacements
shuffle($hello);

echo preg_replace($bye, $hello, $words);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question clearly, if you want to pick a random item from `$bye` array if `$word` is in `$hello` array try this one:

```
$hello = array('hello', 'hi', 'yo', 'sup');
$bye = array('bye', 'seeya', 'aurevoir');
if(in_array($word,$hello))
    echo $bye[array_rand($bye)];
else
    echo "word is not in hello array";
```